# Xml Serialize List of Descendants

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-3.5, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize a list of descendants. This is what I have now, that works fine:

```
class Animal {}
class Zebra:Animal{}
class Hippo:Animal{}

[XmlRootAttribute("Zoo")] 
class Zoo
{
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Zebra))]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Hippo))]
    public List<Animal> Actions
    { set; get; }
}
```

This works fine and I can serialize both `Animal`s. I wonder If it is possible to create an `Attribute` class where I can pass the list of animals (instances), and will create for me the `XmlArrayItem`s attributes.

In general, I am looking for a way to avoid specifying the descendants of `Animal` everytime I create a new one. I want all descendants of `Animal` to be serialized, whatever their type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a list of derived types within an assembly like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Type> GetAllTypesDerivedFrom(Type type)
{
    var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(type).GetTypes();
    return types.Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(type));
}
```

Perhaps you can cycle through a foreach loop on the GetAllTypesDerivedFrom method above, and then fit it into a solution similar to the MSDN example for [XmlArrayItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlarrayitems%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

*NOTE: If you need to get all derived types for an interface, you'll instead need to use the following (would work with both interfaces and classes):*

```
return types.Where(type.IsAssignableFrom).Where(t => t != type);
```